# Coffeescript select the id of a table row

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

How do I extract the ID of a table row using Coffeescript?

HTML:

```
<tbody>
        <tr id="66">
          <td>Meeting</td>
          <td>David Smith</td>
          <td>10/02/2013</td>
          <td>2.0</td>
          <td><button class="add_button" type="button">Add</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="75">
          <td>Add to invoice</td>
          <td>David Smith</td>
          <td>10/22/2013</td>
          <td>0.5</td>
          <td><button class="add_button" type="button">Add</button></td>
        </tr>
```

Coffeescript attempt:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.add_button').click ->
  event = $(this).attr('id')
  alert event
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your indentation is wrong so your click handler is an empty function, you want to say:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.add_button').click ->
    #...
```

Secondly, the `id` attribute is attached to the `<tr>` but your click handler is bound to the `<button>`. The easiest way to get to the `<tr>` is to use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to walk back up the tree:

```
$('.add_button').click ->
  event = $(@).closest('tr').attr('id')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/KsHvB/

Comment: First time I see `$(@)`, I guess it's equivalent to `$(this)`, right?

Comment: @MrYoshiji: Yes, `@` and `this` are interchangeable.